# Was Iron Man worthy of Mjolnir at the end of Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, avengers-endgame, mjolnir

So I rewatched *Avengers: Endgame* earlier on and I was just wondering: Could Iron Man have lifted Thor's hammer in his final moments, considering

> he literally gave his life to save the universe?

Answer (score 7):

Ultimately we don't know because we never see Tony attempt to lift Mjolnir after his Snap. However, there does certainly appear to be more to being worthy than just willing to sacrifice yourself for the good of others. Remember in *The Avengers* Tony pretty much sacrificed himself by carrying the nuke through the wormhole, yet in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* he was not able to lift Mjolnir. So, Tony simply risking giving up his life by performing the Snap isn't necessarily enough to deem him worthy.

I think in both cases though Tony didn't necessarily know he was going to die. Note his comment to J.A.R.V.I.S. after Steve tells him it's a one way trip in *The Avengers*:

> **Steve:** Stark, you know that's a one-way trip?
>
> **Tony:** Save the rest for return, J.
>
> <sub>*The Avengers*</sub>

His facial expressions when the suit freezes up and the systems go offline also give a look of horror and shock like he was expecting a return. Then similarly in *Avengers: Endgame* he doesn't know it is outright going to kill him, he knows it's going to hurt but he also knows both Thanos and Smart Hulk have snapped and lived. For all he knows he could have lived from it as well.

Tony also doesn't really meet with other criteria for worthiness. Compare him to Steve. Steve is always putting others before himself no matter what the cost. Tony, on the other hand, is still putting himself first. Throughout *Avengers: Endgame* he doesn't want to join them to right Thanos' Snap because he doesn't want to put his family and Morgan at risk. Even after joining at the very end before Smart Hulk's snap he's still only thinking about himself and his family.

> **Tony:** Okay, remember, everyone Thanos snapped away five years ago, you’re just bringing them back... *to today*. Don’t change *anything* from the last five years. Got it?
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

I think there's another aspect to this as well, the worthiness enchantment was placed by Odin to make sure Thor was worthy. Of what is debatable but part of it surely relates to ruling Asgard as that is why he banished Thor. Steve and Thor, once he sorted himself out in *Thor*, are worthy of that. They are both born leaders. Tony, not so much so. He can be a leader and might be able to lead small groups of people but being a leader of some place like Asgard which is then the protector of the Nine Realms? No that's not Tony.

He certainly is close to being worthy but that selfish part of his personality has never really gone away completely over the years so he still seems to fall just short of being worthy.